# unable to buy crypto kittie - why is my transaction not going thru?

Tags: myetherwallet, etherscan, cryptokitties

I have tried everything in order to buy a crypto kittie however I have not been able to get a transaction to go thru. In the following receipt you can see I give a Gas Limit of 250,000 and a gas price of 4 gwei and I still get a status of fail. Why is my transaction not going thru?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7ffead50e4166f7893b945efb323a3dfc31b632e5a4c25c27058be50a588b97a